# Ejecutando Tests en Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

necesito ejecutar unos test en ruby, y aunque he seguido los pasos de la documentacion siempre me salen los mismos errores.
He seguido estos pasos:

```
-rake db:test:load
-rake db:test:preparate
```

Tengo ya mi carpeta "test" y en modelos los test de todos los devise que he creado para mi aplicacion. Cuando descomento el codigo:
test "the truth" do
   assert true
  end
y ejecuto el test asi: rails test test/models/contacto_test.rb me sale este error:

> Error: ContactoTest#test_the_truth: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
>   SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email:
>   INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES
>   ('2018-07-28 21:14:19.244199', '2018-07-28 21:14:19.244199',
>   298486374)

test/models/contacto_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ContactoTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end

  #test "guarda_usuario" do
    #contacto = Contacto.new ({nombre:'pepito', apellidos: 'lopez garcia', edad: '56'})
    #assert contacto.save
  #end 
end
```

Por lo visto algo relacionado con la base de datos, pero no se que quiere decir. Me sale siempre el mismo error, da igual el test que le pase, si para que lo pase o para que no y igual con que modelo lo pruebe, siempre me sale el mismo error. Alguien me puede ayudar porfavor? Gracias de antemano

Comment: El error te indica que el registro que estás utilizando para realizar la prueba ya existe en la base de datos y, por lo tanto, no puede crear uno nuevo. ¿Podrías mostrar el contenido del archivo *contacto_test.rb*?

Comment: Hola Gerry, gracias por tu contestación. En test/models tengo en contacto_test.rb el siguiente codigo: require 'test_helper'

class ContactoTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "the truth" do
     assert true
    end 

   
#test "guarda_usuario" do
 #contacto = Contacto.new ({nombre:'pepito', apellidos: 'lopez garcia', edad: '56'})
 #assert contacto.save
#end  
end  Realmente es el mismo código que sale por defecto. No he realizado ningún cambio al respecto.

Comment: Si el error te lo da en `ContactoTest#test_the_truth`, yo creo que estás creando un usuario en otra parte del código, quizás en rails_spec.rb o algún otro archivo de tipo support de tu suite de tests, porque en realidad `assert true` no hace nada. Si agregas a la pregunta el stacktrace completo del error, quizás pueda salir alguna pista de dónde se está creando ese usuario. Y si comentas `test "test_the_truth"` y descomentas `test "guarda_usuario"`, ¿también te tira el mismo error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El archivo de prueba está bien, el problema entonces debe estar en tus *fixtures*. Abre el archivo *test/fixtures/contactos.yml* y asegúrate de actualizar los registros que han sido generados, o bien coméntalos:

```
# one: {}
#   ...
#
# two: {}
#   ...
```

Comment: Efectivamente descomentando los fixtures de varios .yml he conseguido hacer un test. Nunca habría caído en la cuenta de descomentar los fixtures. Sin embargo estoy ahora intentando correr test muy simples, solo para ver si guarda, borra o edita y me salen 2 errores, uno es: Expected false to be truthy y el otro es: undefined local variable or method `save'. La verdad es que los test que ejecuto es de lo mas simple, pero me dan esos dos errores. El único que ha pasado es test "no guardar un cliente sin nombre" do
  cliente = Cliente.new
  assert_not cliente.save
 end , sabrias porque?

Comment: Hola @mantisa, el problema que describes ahora es diferente, necesitaría ver el código completo de tus pruebas para poder brindarte una mejor ayuda. ¿Podrías generar una nueva pregunta donde puedas describir el problema y compartir el código (y, dado que se resolvió el problema actual, aceptar la pregunta dando clic en la paloma verde)? No edites la actual, pues al ser una pregunta distinta modificarías el sentido de la misma y la respuesta actual sería invalidada. La mejor forma de usar SO es una consulta por pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: ok. Hago como me indicas. Gracias.